# Parsing JSON generated by PHP using jquery returns 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am creating a simple module for our senior project that checks whether an email already  exists in the database.
This is the important segment of my php file which displays the formated JSON:

> > `die(json_encode(array(2 => "Email already taken!")));`

For that example, that should return = {"2","Email already taken!"}

And here is the javascript code (that's embedded):

> ```
> $(function() {
>    $("#signin").submit(function() {
>      // validate and process form here
>      $.ajax({
>         type: "GET",
>         url: "mailcheck.php",
>         data: "email="+document.getElementById('email').value,
>         success: function(data) {
>         var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);
>         //display message back to user here
>           document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = parsed.Msg;
>           $("input#email").val("");
>         },  
>      });
>    return false;
>    });
> });
> ```

The problem is, I always get 'undefined'. What's the problem?

Comment: echo json_encode not die()

Comment: Wouldn't `die()` also echo out the contents? http://codepad.viper-7.com/w3uR9C

Comment: the `die()` function echoes out its contents then it will exit, thus leaving the succeeding `echo()` or `die()` statements not displayed.

Comment: if I could not use `die()`, could I use `exit;` instead? I tried exit and it also worked...

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file echo json_encode as @pc-shooter has mentioned. And you do not need to parse JSON if you set `dataType: 'json',` in you ajax call.

You may also need to set to content type in you PHP file.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(2 => "Email already taken!"));
```